# Amazon S3 からファイルをダウンロードするときにでるエラー

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

EC2,S3,ELB,Route53環境です。S3からファイルダウンロードしようとすると上記のようなエラーがでるのですが、どこの修正が必要でしょうか？

```
 Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server.
 When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" 
options when creating a client or provide an instantiated 
Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object. 
(Client error response [status code] 404 [reason phrase] 
Not Found [url] http://111.111.111.111/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

Comment: もし可能でしたら次の点を質問に追記してみてください。そうすると回答が付きやすくなると思います。1. ダウンロードする際のコード 2. IAMロールを設定してるか 2. アクセスキーとシークレットキーを設定しているか

Comment: .htaccessにアクセスキーとシークレットキーを記述してapacheの再起動をしたらできました。

Comment: 解決できたようですね。もしよければご自身で回答を書いてそれに解決マークをつけてみてください。検索した時などに、この解決済みであることが分かるので SOで推奨されてます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webrootに配置してある、.htaccessにEC2のアクセスキーとシークレットキーを記述したら解決しました。IAMロールは設定済みでの環境です。